# Eclipse auto complete without setter and getter

Tags: java, eclipse

how to make eclipse support autocomplete in xhtml files for fields in beans that not have setter and getter.
such that if i have bean like

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userBean")
public class UserBean{
public userName="";
}
```

and have page login.xhtml that have

```
<p inputtext value="#{userBean.userName}"/>
```

eclipse not support autocomplete here

Comment: Not really surprising, since #{userBean.userName} doesn't care about your public userName field, but about a bean **property** named userName, i.e. a getter/setter pair. Stop using public fields.

Comment: i ask about how i can force eclipse to see the public field without getter or setter

Comment: And what I'm telling you is that this wouldn't make sense, because `#{userBean.userName}` means: populate this input with `userBean.getUserName()`, and when submitting the form, call `userBean.setUserName()` with what the user has filled in the input. The problem is not with Eclipse. The problem is about your understanding of how a bean is, and how the expression language works.

Comment: i extends BeanELResolver and force the #{userBean.userName} to work correctly but i want autocomplete work olso

Comment: That's probably not possible. Why don't you do the right thing and use beans as they're supposed to be used: using getters and setters?